# Log.e with Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

As we have used `Log.e()` for logging error with java code. I was looking for same functionality with `Kotlin`. Though i have found Logger class

```
val Log = Logger.getLogger(MainActivity::class.java.name)
Log.warning("Hello World")
```

It is showing log in android studio logcat.

But does there any way to print log in red color the same way Log.e() does?

Comment: You can use `Log.e()` in the Android-Kotlin, too.

Comment: Oh, so there is no specific function defined in `Kotlin` right?

Comment: Kotlin is just the language (plus a very small utility library). It doesn't bring any logging framework with it, but any library you used before will continue working just the same, and that includes everything from the Android Framework like loggers.

Comment: Using built in Android APIs are generally done through the exact same classes and functions that you'd use in Java code as well.

Comment: yes same as do in java `Log.e()`

Comment: The red color output isn't something that Log does, but something that your IDE is doing for you. You can do it yourself if you want to use logcat via shell. You can also access all Java/Android methods just fine via Kotlin code.

Comment: Btw: You can use the `loge` template to generate the code in Java and convert it automatically to Kotlin by copy and pasting it into a Kotlin file. Or, you can make the log templates available in Kotlin by importing the Kotlin port from [this Github repo](https://github.com/TobiasUhmann/android-studio-log-templates-for-kotlin) directly. Just import the .jar via 'File > Import Settings...'.

Answer (score 22):

You can use log like this `Log.d(TAG, "my Message")` in KOTLIN

Comment: Can you had how you set TAG?

Comment: TAG: String and TAG ="my activity"

Comment: In Java, best practice was to go through `private static final` when declaring the TAG. Are you saying that you don't think that something corresponding is best practice in Kotlin?

Answer (score 14):

`Log.e()` will work perfectly in Kotlin.

In Kotlin, we also have a Logger class to log something.

```
Logger.getLogger(Test::class.java.name).warning("Hello..")
```

Otherwise, you have to use some other library like: kotlin-logging, anko logging etc.

Answer (score 4):

As Kotlin guarantee 100% interoperable with Java and Android, you can use `Log` or any java class in kotlin also.

If you insist to use Logger class, you can get the same output as `Log#e` using `Logger#severe`

Anyway, I recommend to use [Timber](https://github.com/JakeWharton/timber) or similar. There are many avantages on using it and using. Android's `Log` class logs all your outputs in any enviroment, and also consumes machine resources that you should get rid in production.

Answer (score 3):

You can use all your java classes from Kotlin, so `Log.e(  )` in java is exactly the same as `Log.e(   )` in Kotlin.

If you want extra capabilities like automatically infering the tag string, you can use something like [AnkoLogger](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko/wiki/Anko-Commons-%E2%80%93-Logging)